# How to frame following complex structure using dictionaries?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary

I need to pass data with following structure to web service.

required structure is :

```
{  
   "Name":"abc",
   "fatherName":"xyz",
   "class":{  
      "id":"1",
      "className":"MPC",
      "classDesc":"Maths,Physics,chemistry"
   },
   "classLeader":{  
      "id":"123",
      "firstName":"def",
      "lastName":"ghi",
      "emailId":"def.ghi@jkl.com"
   },
   "classTeachers":[  
      {  
         "id":"567894",
         "firstName":"xxx",
         "lastName":"V",
         "emailId":"xxx.V@jkl.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have separate dictionaries for `class` , `classLeader` and `classTeachers` dictionaries like this:

```
class = ["id":"1","className":"MPC","classDesc":"Maths,Physics,chemistry"]
classLeader = ["id":"123","firstName":"def","lastName":"ghi","emailId":"def.ghi@jkl.com"
```

and

```
classTeacher = ["id":"567894","firstName":"xxx","lastName":"v","emailId":"xxx.v@jkl.com]
```

and two strings of `name` and `fathername`

I tried to do with `[string:AnyObject]` and passing my dictionaries as anyobject but I am not able to succeed..the output I am getting is

```
{  
   "Name":"abc",
   "fatherName":"xyz",
   "class":[ 
      "id":"1",
      "className":"MPC",
      "classDesc":"Maths,Physics,chemistry"
   ],
   "classLeader":[  
      "id":"123",
      "firstName":"def",
      "lastName":"ghi",
      "emailId":"def.ghi@jkl.com"
   ],
   "classTeachers":[  
      [  
         "id":"567894",
         "firstName":"xxx",
         "lastName":"V",
         "emailId":"xxx.V@jkl.com"
      ]
   ]
}
```

I am not getting any idea how to frame the required structure.Help me in this issue.

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: please check both jsons.... I am gettin `[` inplace of `{` .. that is the error

Comment: This is not error console is displaying dictionary using `[` if you create swift generic dictionary.

Comment: Have you faced problem sending it to server? @NiravD is right.

Comment: yes it is not error but while sending to server, I am getting error because of that one

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: unable to read json

Comment: @varunaaruru Can you show your code of making api request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to `JsonSerialize` the data. Try this.

```
let clas = ["id":"1","className":"MPC","classDesc":"Maths,Physics,chemistry"]
let classLeader = ["id":"123","firstName":"def","lastName":"ghi","emailId":"def.ghi@jkl.com"]
let classTeacher = ["id":"567894","firstName":"xxx","lastName":"v","emailId":"xxx.v@jkl.com"]

let dict = ["name": "ABC", "fatherName": "XYZ", "class": clas, "classLeader": classLeader, "classTeachers": classTeacher]

let jsonData = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: .PrettyPrinted)
let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

print(jsonString)
```

Comment: but while converting to json..I am not getting double quotes

Comment: Edited to reflect the same